# adding files to SitePages

Tags: application-pages

The following code supposed to add copyitem.aspx file to SitePages. I go to the subsite via SP Designer.

I can see "Site Objects" on the left navigation. I click on Site Pages and I get "The Document Library view cannot be displayed for this Web site.". However, I click on All Files (under site objects), I see a "SitePages" with Folder icon and sure enough CopyItem.aspx is there.

Please suggest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="CopyItem" Url="SitePages" Path="CopyItem">
    <File Url="CopyItemTemplate.aspx" Name="CopyItem.aspx" Type="Ghostable" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: FYI: Only Team Collabaration List feature is enabled for the sub-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled the "publishing feature" and sitepages became available and aspx files were saved in that location. Good luck.